# Disabling stellar.js on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, stellar.js

I have built a parallax scrolling site, however I'm having trouble disabling stellar.js for mobile devices. My HTML and CSS are okay but I'm very lacking in JavaScript and jQuery knowledge. I've tried adding the following to the start of my main.js file:

```
function detectmob() {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
        stellarActivated = false;
    } else {
        stellarActivated = true;
    }
}
```

Can some one show me how best to go about this?

Thanks so much.

Comment: What trouble you getting to disabling stellar.js?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the JS or jQuery regex code from this website - http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Then include this library in the head section of your project to detect if the requesting user agent is a mobile device or not. This library provides a bool property `jQuery.browser.mobile` which is true if the requesting device is mobile device, which you can use like this-

```
if(jQuery.browser.mobile)
{
    stellarActivated = false;
}
else
{
    stellarActivated = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser), the accepted answer offers various ways to detect mobile browsers. In your case you could add this to your main.js

```
window.is_mobile = function() {
  var check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
}
```

Then you can set your stellarActivated flag like this:

```
if(window.is_mobile) {
    stellarActivated = false;
}else{
    stellarActivated = true;
}
```

If you set up stellar according to [the documentation](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/docs/) - instead of using a boolean - only fire stellar directly if necessary:

```
if(!window.is_mobile) {
        $(window).stellar();
    }
```

Be sure to check [detectmobilebrowsers.com](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com) for coding examples for detecting mobile browsers in other languages.